# How a socks proxy is different from a normal proxy?

Tags: network, networking, proxy

Socks is a protocol that a proxy uses, then it's called socks proxy. A normal proxy may use any other protocol. How a socks proxy is different from other proxies. What are all the unique features of socks proxy and how it functions while forwarding traffic to the destination?

Comment: Sorry, proxies are application-layer concepts and everything above the transport layer is explicitly off-topic here, see the [help]. There is no such thing as a "normal proxy", it's application specific. Likely, you refer to an HTTP proxy.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Zac67 says, there's no such thing as "normal proxy" as anything can be proxied but with "normal" proxy usually people refer to http proxy. Also this does go beyond the scope of this forum.

But shortly the difference is the protocol used between the client and the proxy server. The question is discussed for example this Stackoverflow thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23591729/whats-the-difference-between-a-socks-proxy-and-a-http-proxy-which-supports-c

A large number of webpages also exist talking about this, for example here are first four results of my quick google search:

- https://oxylabs.io/blog/socks-vs-http-proxy
- https://limeproxies.netlify.app/blog/differences-http-proxy-vs-socks-proxy
- https://dzone.com/articles/breaking-down-complex-differences-of-socks-vs-http
- https://gologin.com/http-vs-socks

Comment: Thanks, the last link cleared my doubts.

Comment: One doubt i've, does the socks proxy use a tunnel?

Comment: Now that's another pretty wide question... depends on the implementation. For example you can use ssh server as a SOCKS proxy. Google for "socks tunnel" (no quotes) and you'll get again a number of sites discussing this, including step-by-step instructions how to set these up. If answer's helpful, in general it'd be appreciated if it's accepted as an answer :-) EDIT oh you did, thank you :-)